# Read a numerical data with many decimal places from Cloud Firestore in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, bigdecimal

I am trying to read a numeric data from Cloud Firestore. This number contains many decimals and from Kotlin I only get the first whole number. I have tried to fix it with BigDecimal, but it still doesn't work. Can you help me? Thank you.

```
fun obtenerDatosBD() {
    var readBTC:Int

    if (email != null) {
        db.collection("users").document(email).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if(it.exists()){
                readBTC = it.getDouble("BTC")?.toInt()!!
                val test = BigDecimal(readBTC)
                println("DATOS: $test")
            }else{
                //No existen datos
                db.collection("users").document(email).set(
                    hashMapOf(
                        "Saldo" to "0,00",
                        "BTC" to 0.000000,
                        "Provider" to provider
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Cloud Firestore IMG]

Answer (score 1):

You are losing all the decimal points here:

`it.getDouble("BTC")?.toInt()!!`

You are reading it as `Double` and then making it an `Int`. Instead you should try and read it as a `String` and give that to the `BigDecimal` constructor.

```
fun obtenerDatosBD() {
    var readBTC: String //Int has no decimal places
    
    if (email != null) {
        db.collection("users").document(email).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.exists()) {
                readBTC = it.getString("BTC") //or `it.get("BTC") as? String?` or something, I don't know what type of object `it` is
                //something to do if readBTC is null, like a return, or have the non existence message in another fun and call it from here as well.
                val test = BigDecimal(readBTC)
                println("DATOS: $test")
            } else {
                //No existen datos
                db.collection("users").document(email).set(
                    hashMapOf(
                        "Saldo" to "0,00",
                        "BTC" to 0.000000,
                        "Provider" to provider
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a String because I need to perform calculations on the received number. Other solution?

Comment: perform the calculations on the BigDecimal. You can't perform the calculations on `Int` either anyway, since it is an [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), a.k.a. a whole number, and will never have a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun obtenerDatosBD() {
        var readBTC:String
        if (email != null) {
            db.collection("users").document(email).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                if(it.exists()){
                    readBTC = it.getString("BTC").toString()
                    val test = BigDecimal(readBTC)
                    val testInt: Double = test.toDouble()
                    println("DATOS: $test + $testInt")
                }else{
                    //No existen datos
                    db.collection("users").document(email).set(
                        hashMapOf(
                            "Saldo" to "0,00",
                            "BTC" to "0.000000",
                            "Provider" to provider
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

}